# Deformation of gradually applied load vs impact loads?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, structural-beam

When a load P is applied gradually on an object, the work done on it is the average of the initial and final loads, which is generally P/2 multiplied by the deflection Δ1. In the case of impact load, the work done is just P x Δ 2 (both on elastic objects that obey Hooke's law).

In both of these cases, the work done is stored as potential strain energy in the object. So, it should mean that when the load is released, the total work done by the object to return to it's unstressed state (assuming elastic deformation) should be the same as the work done to get the object to its stressed state.

1. When the object is released from its stressed state, is the force exerted by the object constant throughout the whole time as it reaches the unstressed state for both the gradually applied and impact loads?
2. Assuming that the force exerted by the object when it is released to be constant throughout, is the deflection of the object in the gradually applied case more or less of that of the impact case?
3. Is the stiffness co-efficient based on gradually applied loads or impact loads?

Comment: Your initial paragraph applies only to systems that obey Hooke's law. You should probably make this explicit since most real world systems do not obey Hooke's law or obey it only to a good approximation.

Comment: Work done on a object is defined as simply force x distance travelled by the object in the direction of the force. Plastic objects should also obey this law, even though they do not return to their original state when the load is removed. Anyway, I have added the statement to simplify it.

Comment: The work done is the average of the initial and final loads times distance **only** if the force changes linearly with displacement i.e. if Hooke's law applies.

Comment: That is only the internal forces induced which do not change linearly in plastic objects.

Comment: The average force on the object is the integral with respect to time of the instantaneous force divided by the time.  In this discussion, are you allowing for a non-uniform deformation of the object as a result of accelerating different parts of the object at different rates?  An impact force will cause a deformation which travels as a wave across the object, even for an object that obeys Hooke's deformation law at every position locally.

Comment: Are you familiar with the 3D version of Hooke's law of elasticity in terms of the components of the stress tensor and the linear strain tensor?